# Filtering by variable's value. How does .filter(**{filter_name: filter_value}) work?

Tags: python, django

So this magic:

```
filter_name = 'some_field_from_model'
filter_value = 'some_val'
Object.filter(**{filter_name: filter_value})
```

works. But how does it work? What does `**` do? I am fascinated but I don't understand this at all. Can someone explain what is happening here? Thanks a lot. Python newb here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `**` before a `dict` in a a function call unpacks the `dict` as if you used named parameters. It has nothing to see with pointers.
Exemple : `function(**{"a":1, "b":42))` is like `function(a=1, b=42)`